# Is there any way to enable the software rasterizer option in chromium?

Tags: chromium

I want to use a gpu when I execute a program but it's impossible 
because the application is already hardcoded "--disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer" options

I already read the api document and chromium source code but 
I can't find out any way to enable gpu with that options.

```
case1) fail (not worked)
"--enable-gpu" : is not worked

case2) fail (not worked)
"--enable-gpu --enable-oop-rasterization --enable-gpu-rasterization --force-gpu-rasterization"
```

Is there any way to enable gpu in this condition?

Comment: Can't you **remove** the command? How is it hardcoded?

Comment: No, I can't remove the command. "--disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer" is already hardcoded.

Comment: "How is it hardcoded?"

Comment: Are you using your own Chromium fork? Those switches are used by render processes and are passed to them when spawning render processes.

Answer (score 0):

```
chromium --disable-gpu --disable-software-rasterizer
```